# How to make this code much simpler and shorter, Java

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a quiz program using swing components. I want to make a code that I will declare all the designs like background color and I will use it to all the frames I created so my code will be simpler and shorter.

I already tried to declare one by one.

```
contentPane1.setBackground(Color.PINK);
contentPane2.setBackground(Color.PINK);
contentPane3.setBackground(Color.PINK);
contentPane4.setBackground(Color.PINK);
contentPane5.setBackground(Color.PINK);
```

I have to create 10 frames, and with that kind of code it will be very long. I don't know how to do it I am just a beginner. Thank you :)

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Stream` of your content pane(s) and invoke `setBackground` with a `forEach` like;

```
Stream.of(contentPane1, contentPane2, contentPane3, contentPane4, contentPane5)
        .forEach(p -> p.setBackground(Color.PINK));
```

It might be even better (for ten) to use an array; perhaps like

```
JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[] { contentPane1, contentPane2, contentPane3, 
        contentPane4, contentPane5, contentPane6, contentPane7, 
        contentPane8, contentPane9, contentPane10
};
Arrays.stream(panels).forEach(p -> p.setBackground(Color.PINK));
```

Comment: Assuming they're using Java 11 they could very well do a `List.of(....).forEach(....)` negating the need to create a stream or an array.